# attached files are wrong... sometimes

Tags: php, email, attachment

As a beginner i created this code

```
$o1 = $_POST['pliki'];
            $o12 = $_POST['pliki2'];

            $o2 = $_POST['o2'];
            $o22 = $_POST['o22'];


            $tab1 = explode(',', $o1);
            $tab12 = explode(',', $o12);

            $tab2 = explode(',', $o2);
            $tab22 = explode(',', $o22);

            if(isset($o2) && (bool) $o2) {  


                $format_wydruku1=$_POST['format_wydruku1'];
                $format_wydruku2=$_POST['format_wydruku2'];




                $to = "mail@mail.com";

                $from = "mail@mail2.com";
                $subject ='Zamówienie od '.$imie.' '.$nazwisko;
                $message = "\n\n";




                $tab111=array_merge($tab1, $tab12);
                $tab222=array_merge($tab2, $tab22);

                for($i = 0; $i<count($tab111); $i++) {
                   $plik2 = "../upload/";
                    $plik2 .= $tab222[$i];


                    $name2 = $tab111[$i];
                    if($i<count($tab1)){
                        $message .= $name2."  ilosc kopii: ".$ile1."   format wydruku:".$format_wydruku1."\n";
                    }else if($i>=count($tab1)){
                        $message .= $name2."  ilosc kopii: ".$ile2."   format wydruku:".$format_wydruku1."\n";
                    }
                }



                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                $headers = "From: $from";
                $semi_rand = md5(time());
                $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

                //$headers .="Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
                $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


                $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                $FfilenameCount = 0;


               for($i = 0; $i<count($tab111); $i++) {
                    if($i<count($tab1)){
                        $plik = "../upload/";
                        $plik .= $tab2[$i];

                        $afile = @fopen($plik,"rb");
                        if(empty($afile)){
                            continue;
                        }


                        $data[i] = @fread($afile,filesize($plik));
                        @fclose($afile);

                        $data[i] = chunk_split(base64_encode($data[i]));
                        $name = $tab111[$i];

                        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
                            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" .
                            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data[i] . "\n\n";
                        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                    }else if($i>=count($tab1)){
                        $plik = "../upload/";
                        $plik .= $tab222[$i];

                        $afile = @fopen($plik,"rb");
                        if(empty($afile)){
                            continue;
                        }


                        $data[i] = @fread($afile,filesize($plik));
                        @fclose($afile);

                        $data[i] = chunk_split(base64_encode($data[i]));
                        $name = $tab111[$i];

                        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" .
                            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" .
                            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data[i] . "\n\n";
                        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                    }
               }

                if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                    echo '<p>Sent</p>';

                } else {
                    echo "<p>error, try again!</p>";
                }
            }else{
```

which sends chosen files with some additional informations. It is working, but... sometimes it sends right files, sometime not... have no idea how to fix it, and where exactly problem is. Names of attached are alway right...

Comment: please explain more `sometimes it sends right files, sometime not`

Comment: I would start by using a *proper* mailer like phpmailer or swiftmailer

Comment: I created two inputs [type=file]. when i'm choosing equal number of files in both inputs it looks like everything is going well, but when numbers are different, files from second input somehow override those from first...